# Sql custom function with Chili's opf3

Tags: c#, sql, orm, opf3

I have to call a previously created function on SQL, like

```
SET  @ExtVALUE = sysdba.GetNextAccountExternalId('{TYPE}')
```

but I can't manage to find if OPF3 has some of this functionality already.

Need to use OPF3, direct access to the SQL connection is not feasible in the architecture.

I think in a solution somewhat like this:

```
var functionQuery = "select sysdba.GetNextAccountExternalId('{0}') as result";

objContext.GetObjectReader<>();
```

What class should I put inside the <> ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record,

```
var functionQuery = String.Format("SELECT sysdba.GetNextAccountExternalId('{0}')", account.Type);

var functionResult = (string)new SqlRawStorageAccess(Context.Storage as SqlStorageBase).
                                CreateCommand(new SqlQuery(functionQuery)).ExecuteScalar();
```

Works.